# Solve logarithm without calculator for exam practice

Tags: logarithms

How to solve
$$\log_{3}(x)+\log_{3}(3x) = 3$$
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Use $\log ab= \log a + \log b$ ,  $\log _a a=1$ And $\log _ab= c \implies b=a^c$ properties

Comment: you just made study night easier. thank you!

Comment: Your welcome :-D

Answer (score 2):

$$log_3 (x) + log_3 (3x) = 3$$
$$log_3(x) + (log_3 (3)+ log_3(x))= 3$$
$$2 log_3(x) + log_3 (3)= 3$$
$$1+ 2 log_3(x) = 3$$
$$log_3(x) =1 $$
$$x=3$$

Answer (score 1):

Given: $\log_{3}(x)+\log_{3}(3x) = 3$.
Then
$$
3^{\log_{3}(x)+\log_{3}(3x)} = 3^3.
$$
Use the rules $\log_a b + \log_a c = \log_a bc$
(or alternatively, $a^{b+c} = a^b \times a^c$) and $a^{\log_a b} = b$
to simplify the left-hand side so it has no more logarithms,
then solve for $x$.

(Notice that all of this is just another way of applying the
hints given in DeNiSkA's answer--there are not really so many different
ways one can manipulate logarithms.)

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_3(x)+\log_3(3x)=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}+\frac{\ln(3x)}{\ln(3)}=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln(x)+\ln(3x)}{\ln(3)}=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln(x)+\ln(3x)=3\ln(3)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln(3x^2)=\ln(3^3)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln(3x^2)=\ln(27)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$3x^2=27\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=9\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=3$$

If we are allowed to use complex numbers $x=-3$ can be a solution.

Comment: $x=-3$ can't be the solution because it is out of the domain of logarithm.

Comment: @DeNiSkA  well, sorta kinda it's a solution. If we take the principal branch for the complex logarithm we get that $\log_{3}(-3)+\log_{3}(-9) = 3 + \frac{2\pi i}{\log 3}$. If we are looking for equality in real part then $-3$ could be considered a valid solution

Comment: @brevan oh, I didn't know that! I dont know complex analysis ;)